# microsoft Botframework webchat speech recognition dynamically set the language code

Tags: botframework, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I am looking for how to set language code dynamically in the webchat, based on user speaking the language.

I tried this

```js
window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
            secret: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }),
        styleOptions: {
            hideUploadButton: true,
            botAvatarInitials: 'Bot'
        },
        selectVoice: (voices, activity) => voices.find(({
            name
        }) => /Kalpana/iu.test(name)),
        //Console.log(activity.locale);
        webSpeechPonyfillFactory: window.WebChat.createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory({
            region: 'xxxx',
            subscriptionKey: 'xxxxx'
        }),
        userID: "ravi@gmail.com",
        locale: 'hi-IN'
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
);

document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
```

Here what I am looking for is, I need to set **locale** parameter dynamically based on user speaking the language.

Comment: Do you want to set the locale based on the users first voice input or based on the language of the browser?

Comment: Base on user speaking language , it has to detect the language and set that language in Locale Parameter . let us suppose user speaking in spanish it has to detect the language and text should be  write in spanish in the webchat . if  he is speaking in german the text should come in german in webchat.

Comment: How many different languages would you like to support? Automatic language detection currently has a services-side limit of four languages per detection, and they just added support for JavaScript.

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-automatic-language-detection?pivots=programming-language-javascript).

Comment: Can we integrate automatic language detection in webchat ? and how to set a user speaking  language to  the webchat  for every user conversation.                             as of now i hard coded the language to  "locale: 'hi-IN'". But this "locale" parameter need to change dynamically based on user speaking language. let me know is this possible or not.